# Creating a 'cooldown'

Tags: java, timer, command, chat

Let's say you have a chatbox, and people are using commands:

```
[userA]: !ping (3sec ago)
[BOT]: Pong.
[userB]: !ping (2sec ago)
[BOT]: Pong.
[userA]: !ping (1sec ago)
//do not respond, 10 second cooldown not over
```

How would I go about creating a different 'cooldown' for different people after they used a command? I made it so that `lastUser` always equals the last username of the person who used a command, so that way you can do stuff with the user within the command response.

I thought about something like this:

```
if(chtBox.command = "!ping"){
>>check if timer with the name/value "lastUser" is active/exists
>>>>if not,
>>>>>>start new 10sec timer with the name/value "lastUser"
>>>>if yes,
>>>>>>ignore command
}
```

Please guide me in the right direction

Comment: Have you attempted the problem?  What **specific** problems did you encounter?

Comment: @LukePark I have tried to make the timer thing work, but I am not sure how to attach a value to timers and how to check if a certain timer exists or is running with a specific value.

Comment: With due respect, your question boils down to "I don't understand so can someone else write me code that will make me understand.", which isn't how StackOverflow works.  We can, however, help you with code that you have written yourself.  Post what you have.

Comment: @LukePark I understand it might seem that way, but I don't necesserily want code. I just need an efficient or 'good' method to go about doing this. I came to Stackoverflow to ask about this. If someone here with more experience could give me an idea, I could code it myself and if I find the solution I will post it as an answer for future people. :-)

Answer (score 0):

This is more a design issue than Java.

Managing a bunch of timers isn't going to be scalable.

Have a collection that tracks when you last heard from any of the clients.

Every n seconds, have a thread wake up, go through the collection, and start "cooldown" on any client who hasn't been heard of in n secs.

Comment: The problem is mainly that it's a chatbot running inside an Android emulator. It checks the database every 500ms for any new inputs, and will sync 'lastUser' with the username. So I don't really have a beautiful way like connecting to clients or whatever... I feel like I have no other option but to use timers. Luckily it will only be used by 10-20 people, so that's a max of 20 timers at a time.

Comment: I'm not saying that you are connecting to clients; just keep track whom you've heard from and then use a second thread to kick people out.